# Is flushing the XML necessary while creating xml

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I am creating an XML file using SAX handler. My code need to insert nearly 30000 records into XML documents as child nodes. My problem is that XML build is stopping suddenly with out creating child nodes in XML file. we are not getting any exceptions in the logs too. Is there any buffer limit for SAX handler while creating XML document

Code:

```
SAXTransformerFactory transformerFactory = SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler handler = transformerFactory.newTransformerHandler();
Transformer transformer = handler.getTransformer();
handler.setResult(streamResult);
handler.startDocument();
```

buildXML method

```
XMLUtil.setStartElement(handler,"abcd");
XMLUtil.setCharacters(handler,"value");
XMLUtil.setEndElement(handler,"abcd");
```

XMLUtil Class

```
setCharacters(TransformerHandler hd,String value){
    if(value !=null){
      hd.characters(value.toCharArray,0,value.getBytes().length)
    }
}

setEndElement(TransformerHandler hd,String value){
    hd.endElement("","",value,null);
}

setEStartElement(TransformerHandler hd,String value){
    hd.startElement("","",value);
}
```

Please check the code.

Generated xml:

```
<abcd>value1</abcd> 
<abcd>value2</
```

PS: This is not happening every time. we're not even getting any exceptions in logs

Comment: There's probably a bug in your code, but we can't tell without seeing it. The most common mistake with SAX is to assume that the characters() method will always receive a complex text node, rather than it being broken up across multiple calls.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've updated the code. Could you please have a look at it.

Comment: What does you xml look like? Both initially and after insertion?

Comment: Adding child nodes is getting stopped suddenly like below.  

   <abcd>value1</abcd>
   <abcd>value2</

Comment: Are you flushing the output properly?

Comment: No I think. Could you please explain how to do that.

Comment: Are you really calling startElement from your endElement method and vice versa? If so, why?

Comment: No, I am not calling like that. That's a Mistake while copying. thanks for finding. I've changed code.

Comment: Is there any code change which I should do?